# Is there a way to install 5D-Embroidery program in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, wine, winetricks

Like the title says. Is there a way to do it? 
[Program icon](https://www.secretsof.com/embroiderytips/freeprojects/SWD/SWD-Installing5DSoftware.pdf)

My art teacher wants to use her lessons to teach other students about this program in computer classroom and in Ubuntu. I understand that if I had dual-boot, this would be an easy fix. I've researched a little bit and found out that you can use SVG2Embroidery converted in inkscape and have Embroidery extensions in inkscape. But, but.. but.. she wants that 5D original program. Help! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that if I had dual-boot, this would be an easy fix.

Sure but there is an even better method: install [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and inside virtualbox you install Windows and can then use it as a regular Windows installation. That way you can use all the Windows software as asked with an easy backup of containers.

> Presently, VirtualBox runs on Windows, Linux, Macintosh, and Solaris hosts and supports a large number of guest operating systems including but not limited to Windows (NT 4.0, 2000, XP, Server 2003, Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows 10), DOS/Windows 3.x, Linux (2.4, 2.6, 3.x and 4.x), Solaris and OpenSolaris, OS/2, and OpenBSD.

A random image from the web to show how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Omg! I didn't think about that. Thanks! I'll think about it. Thanks mate!

Comment: No problems :) It'll be a bit slower than a regular dual boot but the benefits more than enough outweigh that